# Amazon DynamoDB store list of custom objects

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using Amazon DynamoDB for the first time (and it is awesome).  I am working with my the object persistence model so I'm using my own objects to send back and forth.  This is working great on my primitive properties (strings, etc.).  However I also have a property that is a list of other custom objects that I would like to store and I can't get that to commit to the DB.  It's a list of custom objects; each object has a few primitive properties and another list of custom objects (and these have only primitives on them).  I found this:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ArbitraryDataMappingHLAPI.html

and have tried to copy it but can't get it to work.  I also found this on storing maps:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html#DataModel.DataTypes

but that doesn't really seem to work directly with objects unless I'm missing something.  Anyway here is the converter I came up with:

```
public class AwsCommentConverter : IPropertyConverter
{
    public object FromEntry(DynamoDBEntry entry)
    {
        PrimitiveList primList = entry as PrimitiveList;

        if (primList == null)
        { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(); }

        List<CommentVM> comments = new List<CommentVM>();
        foreach (string s in primList.AsListOfString())
        {
            string[] vals = s.Split(new string[] { "$~$" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            if (vals.Length < 3) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

            List<StatusUpdate> updates = new List<StatusUpdate>();
            for (int i = 2; i < vals.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] udVals = vals[i].Split(new string[] { "#@#" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                if (udVals.Length != 4) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

                StatusUpdate ud = new StatusUpdate()
                {
                    StatusType = (StatusUpdate.StatusUpdateType)Enum.Parse(typeof(StatusUpdate.StatusUpdateType), udVals[0]),
                    StatusDate = DateTime.FromFileTime(long.Parse(udVals[1])),
                    UserName = udVals[2],
                    NewValue = udVals[3]
                };

                updates.Add(ud);
            }
            comments.Add(new CommentVM(vals[0], vals[1], updates));
        }
        return comments;
    }

    public DynamoDBEntry ToEntry(object value)
    {
        List<CommentVM> comments = value as List<CommentVM>;
        List<Primitive> storageVals = new List<Primitive>();

        if (comments == null) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

        foreach (CommentVM cm in comments)
        {
            string dta = cm.ID + "$~$" + cm.CommentText + "$~$";
            foreach (StatusUpdate ud in cm.StatusLog)
            { dta += ud.StatusType.ToString() + "#@#" + ud.StatusDate.ToFileTime().ToString() + "#@#" + ud.UserName + "#@#" + ud.NewValue + "$~$"; }

            if (dta.EndsWith("$~$"))
            { dta = dta.Substring(0, dta.Length - 3); }

            storageVals.Add(new Primitive() { Value = dta });
        }
        return new PrimitiveList() { Entries = storageVals };
    }
}
```

Here is the property declaration:

```
    [DynamoDBProperty(typeof(AwsCommentConverter))]
    public List<CommentVM> Comments
```

I set a break point in the converter and it never seems to get hit which leads me to believe I've messed up setting it up, but I'm not sure how...  Can anyone tell me how to get this stored and retrieved?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I figured it out.  The property is read only and apparently that means it is skipped?  It's a list and it doesn't have a setter because the list is constructed on object creation and the list object itself should not really be replaced, although the contents of the list are modified frequently (hence the need to store them in the db).

I added a setter and now it works with the object persistence model and my custom converter...